# Thread Performance in Android

Tags: android, posix

Is there any way to monitor the performance of a thread on Android phone.

As in any POSIX library?

I want to find the time taken by a "thread" during execution, while many other applications might also be running.

Thank You.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linux supports a per-thread CPU usage timer.  Time advances when a thread is executing or (I think) blocked on disk I/O, but does not advance when other threads are executing or the current thread is waiting for an event (e.g. Object.wait()).

You can use it from an Android app by calling `SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis()`.  In C/C++ code in the NDK, you can use the POSIX API `clock_gettime(CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID)`.