# How to obtain computation time in NDK

Tags: android, performance, time, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I need to obtain the computation time of some parts of an algorithm I have implemented in C with NDK/JNI.

I've read this question: [Android Get Current timestamp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077530/android-get-current-timestamp)

I think I can obtain the computation time of a JNI call using the same method in this way:

```
Long start, end, time;
start = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
//my native call
end = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
time = end - start;
Log.i(TAG, "Time ... (ms): " + time);
```

But I need to check the computation times of some small parts inside the native method. How can I do it?

Comment: u can do it by setting log messages before and after the calling method...and then just use time = end - start; I mean print the time in log messages.

Comment: @AllessandroGaietta your example divides `currentTimeMillis()` by 1000... did you want your measurement to be as course as seconds?

Comment: @mah It is a copy error, i don't want divide by 1000 ;D

Comment: @Pratik obviously In the example there is the Log printing. I want to know how to use some similar function INSIDE the JNI call, to obtain the current time and print it in the log (i know how to print Log messages inside the JNI, just don't know how to get the time).

Answer (score 17):

It's best not to use `gettimeofday()` or `currentTimeMillis()` on a mobile device.  These return "wall clock" time, which can jump forward or backward suddenly if the network updates the time.

Use the monotonic clock instead for performance measurements -- `System.nanoTime`() or `clock_gettime()` with `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`.  Note this returns a `struct timespec` rather than a `struct timeval`; primary difference is that the clock resolution is nanoseconds rather than microseconds.

```
int64_t getTimeNsec() {
    struct timespec now;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &now);
    return (int64_t) now.tv_sec*1000000000LL + now.tv_nsec;
}
```

In addition to wall-clock time you may be interested in per-thread CPU time; see [Thread Performance in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564161/thread-performance-in-android/3570077#3570077).

Comment: How frequently is the wall clock time updated? I obtain very different time values between gettimeofday() and clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID) methods. The second one seems more stable, but it's result is a larger time then the first one, instead I expected a smaller time!

Comment: You can tell how often the wall clock timer is updated by calling it as fast as you can in a loop and subtracting the results the first time the value changes.  It varies from device to device and release to release.  The PROCESS_CPUTIME clock only advances when your process does work; if it's asleep, the clock doesn't change.  (I'd recommend CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID for performance work, since it only advances when the current thread uses the CPU.)  The clocks are not tied to each other, and may not start at zero.

Comment: What I mean is that by measuring with clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID) (or THREAD, same results) on a small set of operations (a few milliseconds) I get a time equal to gettimeofday() or a simple clock(). Instead, in long cycles I get a longer time with the first one, and the same, shorter, time with gettimeofday() and clock(). NOTE: in all cases I measure time between an end point and a start point, the result of clock_gettime() is corrected if nanoseconds difference < 0 (seconds++). clock() is translated dividing by CLOCKS_PER_SEC.

Comment: Does the process/thread cpu time include the time that the processor was executing kernel-space instructions, on behalf of the program? Or are they excluded?

Answer (score 7):

From within your C/C++ code,

```
#include <sys/time.h>
long long currentTimeInMilliseconds()
{
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    return ((tv.tv_sec * 1000) + (tv.tv_usec / 1000));
}
```

This will get you a structure with the current time in seconds and microseconds, giving you enough to measure time between two points fairly easily. It then performs the conversion to return the current time, in milliseconds.

Edit: updated per @ChrisStratton's suggestion.

Comment: This would be a more complete answer if you showed the conversion from the struct to a single milliseconds or microseconds value in a 64-bit type...

Comment: I have litle problem with types add L to numbers eg.
    struct timeval stCurrentTime;
    gettimeofday(&stCurrentTime, nullptr);
    return ((long long)stCurrentTime.tv_sec * 1000L) + ((long long)stCurrentTime.tv_usec / 1000L); //millseconds